# Python thread lock all the program

Tags: python, multithreading, tweepy

I'm creating a StreamListener using the twitter Api tweepy and python 2.7.11.

I create a thread in the constructor of a class:

```
 def __init__(self, api=None, **options):

    StreamListener.__init__(self,api)

    self.queue = Queue(maxsize = options.get("queue_size", 100) )
    self.queue_thread = Thread(target=self._listen())
    self.tweet_list = OrganizedList(options.get("list_size", 50))

    #And more code...
```

But the execution of the main program changes to the thread function instead of continue executing the init function. I tried to create the thread with daemon=True but it doesn't work.

The complete code is in https://github.com/pablomm/tweetbot/blob/master/tweetbot/utils.py

How I can make the thread running in the background as it should?

[EDIT]Solved, the right code is

```
def __init__(self, api=None, **options):

    StreamListener.__init__(self,api)

    self.queue = Queue(maxsize = options.get("queue_size", 100) )
    self.queue_thread = Thread(target=self._listen) #<-- without ()
    self.tweet_list = OrganizedList(options.get("list_size", 50))
```

Comment: You probably want `Thread(target=self._listen)` unless `self._listen()` returns a callable object.

Comment: This ^^. Otherwise you're calling the _listen method from your main thread instead of passing it to `Thread()`.

Comment: That's solved my problem, thank you!